# Fetched entities from CoreData don't get annotated on the MKMapVIew

Tags: ios, core-data, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a problem when I was trying to add annotation into my current MKMapView. Below is how I am trying to fetch entities stored in Core data and annotate them into the currently displaying MKMapView.

The issue I am facing is that only newly added entities, which is added from another view controller, are being annotated on the map view. Older data, like ones from few weeks ago, get fetched and added into array, but are not annotated into the map view at all.

Moreover, even if the data is newly added, when I closed the application and then reopen the app again, then the data from previous session wouldn't get annotated as well.

The 'Whale' entity already conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol.

I am really confused here, and have no clue about the cause of the problem.

```
- (void)getWhales:(NSInteger)days{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Whale" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponent setDay:days];
    NSDate *designatedDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponent toDate:_today options:0];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date > %@", designatedDate];
    NSLog(@"date is %@", designatedDate);
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    _whales = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"number of whales found: %d", [_whales count]);

    [self.map addAnnotations:_whales];
}
```

Comment: Problems with annotations are often caused in `viewForAnnotations`. You should share your code for that too.

Comment: Hi Craig, I did not implement viewForAnnotations. I just implement `-(NSString *)title` and `-(NSString *)subtitle` in Whale class. These functions along with MKAnnotation protocol usually suffice for annotations, I assume?

Comment: I'm surprised you see anything at all if you don't do your own viewForAnnotations, but perhaps there is a default implementation that uses the title and subtitle. That would certainly solve most of the MKMapView questions I have seen here.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:viewForAnnotation:

Comment: Yep, I plan to implement viewForAnnotation afterwards, but now am still stuck at this simple default annotation. Really have no idea why it's not working here. :(

Comment: You don't need to implement viewForAnnotation for a default pin.  Are you saying that "number of whales found" is correct but you don't see all of them on the map?  Log the coordinates of all the whales in the array.  Make sure the coordinates of the "old" whales are correct (and not eg. 0,0).  Are coordinates of "old" whales very close to "new" whales?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina You are right! Somehow all the coordinates of the "old" whales got reset every time the app closes. Now all the "old" whales are actually pinned in the middle of ocean, south of Ghana, which I presume that this position is coordinates 0.00 , 0.00. Don't know how these coordinates stored in Core Data get reset, though. Anyway, I will find out.